# How to write Maxx dax function to get maximum value per each group

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get Max of fee rate for each stream. I want to get the result as desired max fee highligted in yellow as shown in the table below.

I tried this dax calculation:

```
Desired max fee = MAXX(VALUES('Session Budget Tracker'[Stream]),CALCULATE(MAX('Session Budget Tracker'[Session Fee ($)]),ALLEXCEPT('Session Budget Tracker','Session Budget Tracker'[Stream])))
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to get the correct values please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculate as shown below. it is taking the max based on each stream.

```
Desired max fee = 
    var progStream = 'Session Budget Tracker'[Stream])
    return CALCULATE(MAX('Session Budget Tracker'[Session Fee ($)]), FILTER('Session Budget Tracker','Session Budget Tracker'[Stream] = progStream))
```

Comment: Have you tied this already, please accept answer when this works for you.